# How do I get the typeparam names from a generic type definition?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, system.reflection

Suppose I have a generic type definition as such:

```
var type = typeof(IReadOnlyDictionary<,>)
```

How would I get the typeparam name of the generic arguments?  In the example above, I'm looking for `"TKey"` and `"TValue"`

for `typeof(IList<>)` I am expecting `"T"`

Is there any way, using reflection, to get these strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Type.GetGenericParameterConstraints`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.type.getgenericparameterconstraints(v=vs.110).aspx) for this:

```
var type = typeof(IReadOnlyDictionary<,>)
var names = type.GetGenericArguments().Select(x => x.Name);
```

See my [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9zjgrf).

Comment: Lesson learned - Before I posted I assumed that the names of the types returned by GetGenericArguments wouldn't work.  I should have just tried it out!  Thanks for the quick response here.

Comment: @SFun28 Yeap, that´s exactly what I did myself. Didn´t know of this either. Next time just search a bit.